# Site Upgraded from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 - Datasheet View error

Tags: error, datasheet

When I try to put my "upgraded 2007 to 2010" list in "Datasheet View" I get an error:

This list cannot be displayed in Datasheet View for one or more of the following reasons:

- A datasheet component compatible with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation is not installed.
- Your Web Browser does not support ActiveX controls.
- A component is not properly configured for 32-bit or 64-bit support.

The first one, I would think, is out because I installed SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.
The second one is out because it worked for my old site and I have the site under my "Local Internet" security allowing all.
The third one seems unlikely because the old site was 64-bit also.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just a lucky guess, but are you using Office 2010 x64, because:

> The Edit in Datasheet view functionality is not supported if you install 64-bit Office 2010. However, the functionality is available if you install 32-bit Office 2010.

Source: [64-bit editions of Office 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681792.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Office 2010 64-bit with SharePoint 2010 64-bit (I didn't know they made a 32-bit)

I found the answer:
If you are already runnig Office 2010 64-bit just install **2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components** from Microsoft's site.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en

It works fine now.

Comment: The "official line" is to only run Office 64-bit if you need big Excel spreadsheets. Otherwise it's not necessary and you can run into compatibility problems like this.

Comment: There are a number of issues with the 64-bit version of office, I would stay away.